# Ruby 1.8.7 Regex Buffer Overflow

Tags: ruby, regex, brakeman

I am trying to run brakeman checks for code that is (unfortunately) written in Ruby 1.8.7. At times this entire build breaks and spits out the following error:

`regexp buffer overflow While processing`

I noticed that in ruby 1.8.7 the buffer seems to be about 5460. I found this by running the following

```
 REGEX = /.*(?=[x])/

(0..10_000_000).each do |i|
  begin
    ss = StringScanner.new("a" * i + "x")
    ss.scan(REGEX)
  rescue RegexpError => e
    p i
    break
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

This error is raised by ruby's StringScanner class. I did some digging and found that the error is being raised here: https://github.com/sj26/ruby-1.9.3-p0/blob/master/ext/strscan/strscan.c#L444. Does anybody know what causes this error to be raised. Moreover, why did this suddenly fail after introducing templates?

Comment: What is `REGEX` ? Is it a precompiled variable and you're passing target string `"a" * i + "x"` to it ? If `REGEX` is a class level object, I'm not sure garbage collection is done between begin and end. If `REGEX` is an instance variable, it should be alright since you're just passing a target string to it. Either way seems strange.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity , updated the description.

Comment: Wow, how long does it take to do 0..5460 `"a" * i + "x"` ? Better to start with `5300..10_000` and see where it stops. If you get farther, then it's probably not the buffer size. If you can't, sounds like the most any capture buffer can hold is around 5460 because `.*x` will try to match everything. OR, the stack is the problem. Try initializing the string _outside_ the stack. Do `str = "a" * i + "x"` then `REGEX.match( str )` because it does sound like a stack problem.

Comment: You do not need to run Brakeman with the same version of Ruby that your application is running. Brakeman does not officially support running on Ruby 1.8.7.